# Elected candidates badge's are not retina-ready

Tags: bug, moderator-election, retina

While voting in the moderation election, I've noticed the voted candidate badges are pixelated in retina screens:

[image: Pixelated badge]

(random candidate shown for ilustrative purposes only - not necessarily my vote)

It's the only part of the page seems to not be retina-ready.

Comment: There's a [three-year-old feature-request on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131045/134300). I can see them not wanting to change the default flair size, for all of the sites that have embedded them assuming their existing size, but adding a higher-res option and using it appropriately on this site itself would be nice.

Comment: Your title was the funniest thing I have read today. Thank you (I have a very boring job).

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner And your name was the funniest thing *that I have read today.* So thank *you*. :)

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner I still don't get the pun - if any. You can try [working with us](http://manas.com.ar/workwithus/) - the job definitely isn't _boring_.

Comment: Can we all agree to stop calling high resolution displays "retina?" We're well beyond that, now.

Comment: This is a feature of my flair. I have the ability to short-circuit displays and burn out retinas at will due to my... unique... looks.

Comment: @EdCottrell, I would say that is (one of) the funniest thing *I have read* today. The only reason it isn't the one-and-only is because I was reading an old posts about [the many memes of meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) and [fantasy secret hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213211/what-are-the-fantasy-secret-hats-youd-wish-to-get).

Comment: @CalebKleveter that's fair; those are quality posts.